# Not matches for working regex in c

Tags: c, regex

I want to match the regex `(?<=SEARCH_THIS=").+(?<!"\n)` in C with PCRE.

However, the following code doesn't work as expected.

```
#include <pcreposix.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void){
    regex_t re;
    regmatch_t matches[2];
    char *regex = "(?<=SEARCH_THIS=\").+(?<!\"\n)";
    char *file = "NO_MATCH=\"0\"\nSOMETHING_ELSE=\"1\"\nSOME_STUFF=\"1\"\nSEARCH_THIS=\"gimme that\"\nNOT_THIS=\"foobar\"\nTHIS_NEITHER=\"test\"\n";

    puts("compiling regex");
    int compErr = regcomp(&re, regex, REG_NOSUB | REG_EXTENDED);
    if(compErr != 0){
        char buffer[128];
        regerror(compErr, &re, buffer, 100);
        printf("regcomp failed: %s\n", buffer);
        return 0;
    }
    puts("executing regex");
    int err = regexec(&re, file, 2, matches, 0);
    if(err == 0){
        puts("no error");
        printf("heres the match: [.%*s]",matches[0].rm_eo-matches[0].rm_so,file+matches[0].rm_so);
    } else {
        puts("some error here!");
        char buffer[128];
        regerror(err, &re, buffer, 100);
        printf("regexec failed: %s\n", buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The console output is:

```
compiling regex
executing regex
some error here!
regexec failed: No match
```

I verified the functionality of this regex [here](http://regex101.com/r/dT3gD8/1)
Any idea what is going wrong here?

**EDIT #1**

Compiler Version

```
 $ arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-gcc --version
 arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-gcc (GCC) 4.2.1
 Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
 This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
 warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Compile Command

```
 $ arm-merlin-linux-uclibc-gcc -lpcre ./re_test.c -o re_test.o
```

Comment: Worked for me, sort of - BTW, the `%*` is actually aligning the string, *not* restricting the length of the string.

Comment: For future reference, when posting a question like this, please include information on what compiler version and compile flags you are using.

Comment: can you try `/(?<=SEARCH_THIS=\\")[^\\"]+/` [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dT3gD8/2)

Comment: Working on ubuntu (also sort of) linking against pcreposix.a

Comment: @user3218114 - that doesn't appear to work. This: `(?<=SEARCH_THIS=\")[^\"]+` gives roughly the same result as OPs code.

Comment: I've never used PCRE before - what is the actual expected output after the 'no error' bit?

Answer (score 1):

There are actually a few issues with your code.

First, you use `%*s` in an attempt to restrict the length of the printed string. However, the integer width before the `s` formatter is the *minimum* length of what gets printed; if the corresponding string's length is less than what's given, it'll be padded with spaces. If the length is *greater* than what's given, it'll just output the whole string. You'll need some other method of restricting the length of the outputted string (just avoid modifying `*file`, because `file` points to a constant string).

Second, you specify the `REG_NOSUB` option in your `regcomp` call, but [according to the man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?regcomp+3), this means that no substring positions are stored in the `pmatch` argument - thus, even if your `regexec` *did* work, the following `printf` would be using uninitialized values (which is undefined behavior).

Finally, I suspect the problem is that the `\"` and `\n` characters need to be *doubly*-escaped; i.e. you need to use `\\\"` and `\\n` in your regex string. While the code you gave worked for me (Ubuntu 14.04 x64), the doubly-escaped version *also* works.

Taking all of this into account, this is the output I get:

```
compiling regex
executing regex
no error
heres the match: [.gimme that"]
```

Comment: What does your output look like when you've implemented these?

Comment: @roelofs added output to answer

Comment: I implemented the changes, but am still getting the NOT_THIS and THIS_NEITHER portions.  Still fiddling.

Comment: @roelofs did you also fix the issue with restricting the length? Might help to also print the length of the match.